# CSS: What does the question mark at the end of css do?

Tags: css

Example from Wikipedia css:

```
#content a[href^="https://"], .link-https {
  background:url("images/external-link-ltr-icon.png?2") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
  padding:0 13px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the `?2` at the end of the background URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's actually not part of CSS itself, but rather, part of the querystring to the image.

It's the same as:

```
http://foo/images/external.png?bar=baz
```

The site will take that querystring parameter and value as part of the request. It could make a decision on which file to serve, based on the value supplied.

Likely it's a version number. It helps get around the situations where your browser may have cached the image.

Answer (score 2):

This is (*usually*) used to invalidate the cached version of the image..

When ever you make a new version of the image, you change the number forcing browsers to reload and not use the cached version..

Not part of CSS, but rather the browser behaviour..

Comment: Should I add a "?1" to background images that I will probably never change?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. But you can do it if you change it to force browsers to refresh its cache.

Comment: @gooday, nope. That is a *trick* to use **after** you need to invalidate the cache..

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a so-called cache-buster. It works by the server setting a far future cache expiry date and every time the designer changes that image he can increment the number in the stylesheet and the image will be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

There's no question mark there except for the one in the URL.  That one works just like in any HTTP url; the stuff after it is a query string, to be interpreted however the script that responds to the request chooses to interpret it.

In the case of a static image, this is a technique often used to defeat caching.  The number's a bit too small to suggest that, though.  The query-string part might be used to denote the version of the image, so that caches don't return an image that'd no longer work with the layout.  That's just a guess, though.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark isn't part of the CSS, it's used to request a non-cached version of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone said, it's part of the URL.  The purpose is [cache-busting](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2010/01/11/asp-net-performance-part-3-cache-busting.aspx).  When the image changes, so does the parameter, so clients will get the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CSS feature, it's a feature of URLs; the question-mark denotes the start of the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).